# Booking validation in a big if-elseif block

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I have pasted a part of my event handler code block. I understand this code really looks like a mess specially the object that is created every time the message is changing. Is cleanup possible in this code? Any inputs will help.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', procs.debounce(bookDiningBtnHandler, 400));
var bookDiningBtnHandler = function() {
    btnContext = this, message = {};
    btnContext.touchEnabled = false;
    btnContext.children[0].bubbleParent = 'false';      
    hideKeyBoard();
    // Avoid overlap of keyboard with the prompt..
    removeDatePicker();
    // Avoid overlap of picker with the prompt..

    var isValidEmail = procs.checkValidEmail(email.value);
    var isIntPositive = procs.isPositiveInteger(guest.value);

    if (name.value != '' && isValidEmail != false && isIntPositive != false && guest.value > 0 && date.text != 'Date' && time.text != 'Time') {
        if (guest.value > guestLimit) {
            message = {
                "ref" : 0,
                "title" : "Attention",
                "text" : "Booking for more than 6, Please book through XYZ!"
            };
            customAlert(message);
            return;
        }
        booking = {
            "action" : "diningBook",
            "emailReservations" : Alloy.Globals.data.dining.ER,
            "name" : name.value,
            "email" : email.value,
            "guest" : guest.value,
            "date" : date.text,
            "time" : time.text
        };

        if(checkLastBooked(booking, Alloy.Globals.BDD)){
            message = {
                "ref" : 0,
                "title" : "Attention",
                "text" : "Bookings were made earlier!"
            };
            customAlert(message);   
            return;         
        }               
        Alloy.Globals.BDD = booking;                    
        procs.sendEmail(booking, function(e) {
            treatTheAnswer(e);
            customAlert(message);
            //Ti.API.info('email  passed!');
        });
        function treatTheAnswer(resultSentEmail) {
            if (resultSentEmail) {
                message = {
                    "ref" : 0,
                    "title" : "Booking sent",
                    "text" : "A member of our team will contact you to confirm your BK"
                };
            } else {
                message = {
                    "ref" : 1,
                    "title" : "Error ",
                    "text" : "Something went wrong. Please try again later!"
                };
            }
        }

    } else {
        message = {
            "ref" : 0,
            "title" : "Missed info",
            "text" : "Missing information, Please fill in all fields!"
        };
        if (!isValidEmail && isIntPositive) {
            message = {
                "ref" : 1,
                "title" : "Error",
                "text" : " Invalid Email Address. Please re-enter valid Address!"
            };
        }
        customAlert(message);
        //Ti.API.info(' validation  failed!');

    }
};
```

Comment: I'd post a bit more than this. What you have is good (for review), but with a bit more code we can probably give you a better answer.

Comment: I have edited and added a more meaningful part of the code. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Edited title to be more interesting and removed the performance tag; the code on display does not take particularly long to execute, nor does the question itself indicate that performance is vital.

Answer (score 2):

### Conditionals

`isValidEmail != false && isIntPositive != false`

I'd make that `isValidEmail == true && isIntPositive == true`. You could even short these to `isValidEmail && isIntPositive`. This makes your code more readable AND uses less characters (less that has to be read). It's a win-win.

```
var isIntPositive = procs.isPositiveInteger(guest.value);
... isIntPositive != false && guest.value > 0 ...
```

I don't know what `isPositiveInteger` does, but I have the feeling this check (`guest.value > 0`) is redundant. If you don't allow 0 then explicitly decline that value with `guest.value != 0`.

### Duplication

You have a lot of `message = { ... }`. I'd create a separate function that takes the arguments. Then I'd create separate functions for the constants to be wrapped in, so you get things like this:

```
function createInvalidEmailMessage(){
    return createMessageObject(1, "Error", "Invalid Email Address. Please re-enter valid Address!");
}
function createMessageObject(ref, title, text){
    return {
        "ref": ref,
        "title": title,
        "text": text
    };
}
```

Comment: haha true that :-)

Comment: your comments certainly were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Reduce `if` nesting**

You are already returning early (for example `guest.value > guestLimit`), you could do this for the outer-most `if` as well. This would reduce nesting and make your code generally easier to read.

**Remove `message` variable**

You are always alerting the message right after creating it, and then you are not using it anywhere else. Your code would get more readable if you just remove the `message` variable and pass the message directly.

**Remove `treatTheAnswer`**

As `treatTheAnswer` is only used once, and the name doesn't really add any information, I would just remove it.

**Misc**

- comments for a code line should be either above that line or behind that line, not below it.
- you should declare variables explicitly using `var` (eg `booking`, `btnContext`, etc).

If you do all this, in addition to the great points of [@Pimgd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64975/49695), your code might look like this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', procs.debounce(bookDiningBtnHandler, 400));
var bookDiningBtnHandler = function () {
    var btnContext = this;
    btnContext.touchEnabled = false;
    btnContext.children[0].bubbleParent = 'false';
    hideKeyBoard(); // Avoid overlap of keyboard with the prompt..
    removeDatePicker(); // Avoid overlap of picker with the prompt..

    var isValidEmail = procs.checkValidEmail(email.value);
    var isIntPositive = procs.isPositiveInteger(guest.value);

    if (name.value == '' || !isValidEmail || !isIntPositive || guest.value == 0 || date.text == 'Date' || time.text == 'Time') {
        if (!isValidEmail && isIntPositive) {
            customAlert(createMessageObject(1, "Error", "Invalid Email Address. Please re-enter valid Address!"));
        } else {
            customAlert(createMessageObject(0, "Missed info", "Missing information, Please fill in all fields!"));
        }
        return;
    }
    if (guest.value > guestLimit) {
        customAlert(createMessageObject(0, "Attention", "Booking for more than 6, Please book through XYZ!"));
        return;
    }

    var booking = {
        "action": "diningBook",
        "emailReservations": Alloy.Globals.data.dining.ER,
        "name": name.value,
        "email": email.value,
        "guest": guest.value,
        "date": date.text,
        "time": time.text
    };

    if (checkLastBooked(booking, Alloy.Globals.BDD)) {
        customAlert(createMessageObject(0, "Attention", "Bookings were made earlier!"));
        return;
    }

    Alloy.Globals.BDD = booking;
    procs.sendEmail(booking, function (resultSentEmail) {
        if (resultSentEmail) {
            customAlert(createMessageObject(0, "Booking sent", "A member of our team will contact you to confirm your BK"));
        } else {
            customAlert(createMessageObject(1, "Error", "Something went wrong. Please try again later!"));
        }
    });

    function createMessageObject(ref, title, text) {
        return {
            "ref": ref,
            "title": title,
            "text": text
        };
    }
};
```

You can see that `customAlert` is always used like this: `customAlert(createMessageObject(...))`, so you might want to move the `customAlert` directly into `createMessageObject`.

You might also want to rephrase the first `if` statement like this (it's slightly different logic, but I think more correct and easier to read):

```
if (name.value == '' || date.text == 'Date' || time.text == 'Time' || !isIntPositive || guest.value == 0) {
    customAlert(createMessageObject(0, "Missed info", "Missing information, Please fill in all fields!"));
    return;
}
if (!isValidEmail) {
    customAlert(createMessageObject(1, "Error", "Invalid Email Address. Please re-enter valid Address!"));
    return;
}
```